# Use dynamic variable name

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get the value of `ip_address` from the following yaml that I'm including as variables on ansible:

```yaml
common:
  ntp:
  - time.google.com
node1:
  default_route: 10.128.0.1
  dns:
  - 10.128.0.2
  hostname: ip-10-128-5-17
  device_interface: ens5
  cluster_interface: ens5
  interfaces:
    ens5:
      ip_address: 10.128.5.17
      nat_ip_address: 18.221.63.178
      netmask: 255.255.240.0
version: 2
```

However the network interface (`ens5` here) may be named something else, such as `eth0`. My ansible code is this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Read configuration from the yaml file
      include_vars: "{{ config_yaml }}"

    - name: Dump Interface Settings
      vars:
        msg: node1.interfaces.{{ cvp_device_interface }}.ip_address
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg }}"
      tags: debug_info
```

Running the code like this I can get the key's name:

```
TASK [Dump Interface Settings] *************************************************
│ ok: [18.221.63.178] => {
│     "msg": "node1.interfaces.ens5.ip_address"
│ }
```

But what I actually need is the value (i.e: something like `{{ vars[msg] }}`, which should expand into `{{ node1.interfaces.ens5.ip_address }}`). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-variable-name-programmatically debug; msg : "{{ node1['interfaces'][cvp_device_interface]['ip_address']}}", try this.

Comment: That worked! If you post that as a solution I'll mark that as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sqare brackets.

Example: a minimal playbook, which defines a variable called "device". This variable is used to return the active status of the device.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    device: enx0050b60c19af
  tasks:
    - debug: var=device
    - debug: var=hostvars.localhost.ansible_facts[device].active
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook example.yaml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "device": "enx0050b60c19af"
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars.localhost.ansible_facts[device].active": true
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

see comment

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Read configuration from the yaml file
      include_vars: "{{ config_yaml }}"

    - name: Dump Interface Settings
      debug:
        msg: "{{ node1['interfaces'][cvp_device_interface]['ip_address'] }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg }}"
      tags: debug_info
```